# skip some data from an object rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently i am getting all records from `database` through this line

```
@share_requests = CameraShareRequest.all.includes(:user, :camera).decorate
```

at some points in

```
<tr>
  <td><%= camera_share_request.email %></td>
  <td><%= link_to camera_share_request.camera.name, camera_path(camera_share_request.camera) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to camera_share_request.user.fullname, user_path(camera_share_request.user) %></td>
  <td><%= camera_share_request.message %></td>
  <td><%= camera_share_request.share_rights %></td>
  <td><%= camera_share_request.user_status %></td>
  <td><%= camera_share_request.share_created_at %></td>
</tr>
```

there few entries where there is no `camera_share_request.camera or user` i want to skip those entries from my `@share_requests` object, how it will be possible i tried to do it with `unless` but failed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be:

```
@share_requests = CameraShareRequest.joins( :user, :camera ).decorate
```

Comment: it worked but can you explain that what its doing? consider me as a newbie please

Comment: is there anyway that i can see those who dont have `:user` and `:camera`?

Comment: It's a standard join. The result will be a collection of rows combining data from `camera_share_requests`, `users` and `cameras` where camera_share_requests.user_id == users.id and camera_share_requests.camera_id == camera.id. Since a null user_id or camera_id column won't match anything, those rows aren't included in the result.

Comment: As for those rows that don't have a user or camera, you'd want `CameraShareRequests.where( "user_id is null and camera_id is null" )`. Replace `and` with `or` if you want records where either one is missing.

Comment: thanks but can i see that which are those rows which arent fullfilling this condition?

Comment: [This link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) will give you an introduction to joins and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not` to negate a `.where` and ignore records without cameras or users:

```
CameraShareRequest.where.not(user_id: nil, camera_id: nil).includes(:user, :camera).decorate
```

This will result in SQL looking like:

```
SELECT "camera_share_requests".* FROM "camera_share_requests"  WHERE ("camera_share_requests"."user_id" IS NOT NULL) AND ("camera_share_requests"."camera_id" IS NOT NULL)
```

If the `user_id` or `camera_id` may exist, but the `User` or `Camera` has been deleted, you can skip those records when you print your table:

```
@share_requests.each do |share_request|
  next unless share_request.user && share_request.camera
  # Print row
end
```

Comment: actually i dont want to print it untill its filtered, cant i do something like `@share_requests.each do |share_request|
  next unless share_request.user && share_request.camera
  @share_requests = share_request
end`??? @share_requests only contains those who have user and camera?

Comment: + i did the first .not.where query but it still giving me error on view page as `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You both queries gave me the same results as 674 entries in db with /without any conditions? why is it so?